# Android - How to have a variable width layout with an image at either end and text in the middle

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout for a callout bubble that includes an image on the left, another image on the right and then a layout in the middle which includes a couple of TextViews.

If the length of either TextView is short enough, I want the whole callout to only be wide enough to show the text; if it's too long I want it trimmed with a '...'.

Here's a sample of the XML I'm dealing with (I've stripped out all the margins and padding etc. for clarity):

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/callout" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="54dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/callout_img_left" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/callout_info" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/callout_img_left">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/callout_name" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:ellipsize="end" 
          android:singleLine="true" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/callout_text" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:ellipsize="end" 
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_below="@id/callout_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/callout_img_right"
      android:layout_width="48dp" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/callout_info"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Originally I had the image on the right using `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` but this made the whole callout fill it's available width. The XML shown above works for short text, but if the text is too long it pushes out (shrinks?) the image on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a nested LinearLayout with a zero width will do the trick:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/callout"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="54dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/callout_img_left" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/callout_name" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:ellipsize="end" 
          android:singleLine="true" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/callout_text" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:ellipsize="end" 
          android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/callout_img_right"
      android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you don't mind the two text views always having the same width, you can dispense with the nested LinearLayout and just give each TextView a width of 0dp and weight of 1.

Comment: I'd actually tried that already, but it didn't work. Same problem as per my example above, the text view just expands horizontally until the image view on the right is pushed off. Then it adds the ellipsis.

Comment: @MickByrne - Ah. I understand the problem now. I changed the layout in my answer to (I hope) address this.

Comment: Thank you! The `android:layout_weight="1"` was all it needed.